# Interface with a property that has an interface as its type; class specifies implementation of interface but is invalid

Tags: c#

Apologies if this is duplicate, I imagine it is, but I haven't been able to find anything. I'm probably searching for the wrong thing.

```cs
public interface IMyThingA {}
public class A : IMyThingA {}

interface IMyThingB {
    IMyThingA SomeThingA { get; set; }
}

public class B : IMyThingB {     // B does not implement interface member 'IMyThingA.SomeThingA'
    public A SomeThingA;
}
```

I expected, with the above code, that the class `B` would be able to use a class which implements the expected interface (`IMyThingA`), but clearly I am mistaken. Is there a way to have a pattern like this work?

Comment: Imagine you had `public class OtherA : IMyThingA {}` and tried the following: `IMyThingB b = new B(); b.SomeThingA = new OtherA();` This should illustrate, why this doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with generics and a [type constraint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/constraints-on-type-parameters). For example:

```
public interface IMyThingA { }
public class A : IMyThingA { }

interface IMyThingB<T> where T : IMyThingA
{
    T SomeThingA { get; set; }
}

public class B : IMyThingB<A>
{     
    public A SomeThingA { get; set;}
}
```